# Is any limitation to implementing a web browser login for Facebook authentication in an Expo app

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, facebook-login

I am developing an Expo app with Node.js backend, and I would like to enable users to authenticate using their Facebook. The desired flow involves the user clicking on a login button in the app, which opens a expo browser for authentication. After successful login, the user should be redirected to a Node.js server, where I need to listen for URL changes and extract the authentication token and user information. Is Facebook has any limitation for this implementation ? Because Embedded Browser is disabled by Facebook

When I attempted to use a local IP address in my Expo app for Facebook authentication, it worked, but a warning message was displayed.